# How to retrieve http or https in URI

Tags: php

I need to do something based on either http or https. For example:

```
$https = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https') !== false;
if ($https) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 'a';
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var b = 'b';
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

But this doesn't work. It always goes to the second option regardless the page I access is http or https. Is there any work around? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be done with JavaScript alone, check `document.location.protocol` instead of conditionally building different `<script>` tags.

Comment: Thanks, although I need this in part of php script, your input is still useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))` instead.

Comment: Don't use `isset`, instead test that `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is equal to `"On"` (because it can also be set but equal to `"Off"`). This variable indicates if the request is secure.

Comment: @Dai I believe this is only the case for IIS. In general, if this value is nonempty, then the page was accessed via HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` only returns the path relative to the server root, not the domain or protocol. Besides, your code would fail if I were to access `http://example.com/https-is-cool`.

Instead, try:

```
$https = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== "off";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443){
    echo 'https';
}else{
    echo 'http';
}
```

or as a variable:

```
$https = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with @MichaelBertwoski's comment that if you are simply trying to do this for javascript, do the detection in javascript like this.

```
if (window.location.protocol == 'https:') {
    var a = 'a';
} else {
    var b = 'b';
}
```

If you need the information in PHP you can use one of the other answers posted.